# PouchDB sync deleted DB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a remote CouchDB named 'mydb', and a local PouchDB at client side sync with it. The situation is client can go offline and back, so during client offline, I DELETED the remote 'mydb' and re-create one with same name and added some random new files to the new db.

When the client come back online, is it going to sync back the old file and overwrite those with same name?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

If you need **bi-directional** replication you might do:

```
// use "sync"
localDB.sync(remoteDB)

// another option is to use "replicate" with both "to" and "from"
localDB.replicate.to(remoteDB)
localDB.replicate.from(remoteDB)
```

If you need **uni-directional** replication, you might do:

```
// use "replicate" with only "to"
localDB.replicate.to(remoteDB)
```

Take a look at [this](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html#setting-up-sync).